# Where can I find and tame Chichu?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I've read that the Chichu monster type makes one of the best `COM` classes in the game. Where are they located so that I can tame them? And about what level do I need to be to stand a chance of taking them out with 4 or 5 stars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the strategy guide, you can find Chichu in the *Archlyte Steppe -??? AF-*. In order to get its crystal, you need the *Improved Moogle Throw* fragment skill. If you have it, throw Mog into a patch of red flowers on the Plains of Eternity.

Because the Chichu monster crystal is one of a few only found using Mog, you don't fight it, so you could theoretically be any level as long as you have the improved Moogle Throw (which you get with the [*Mog's Manifestation* fragment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49541/3389)) and access to the *Archlyte Steppe -??? AF-*.