# How Do I Get "Improved Moogle Throw"?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I have the basic Moogle Throw ability - but where do I get the "improved" version which allows me to access certain items I can't otherwise reach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point in Episode 3, you'll unlock *Serendipity -??? AF-*, which is like a giant casino. There, you'll meet a mystic who will teach you about skill fragments.

She'll also give you  *Mog's Manifestation* as part of a starter package of skill fragments: this fragment provides *Improved Moogle Throw*.